# How can I duplicate a Ruby core class name and still use that core class in my class?

Tags: ruby

I am creating a very limited Time class in which I want to make use of the core Time class's parse method.  So I end up with something like this...

```
class Time
    def parse(str)
         @time = # I want to use Time.parse here
    end
end
```

How can I break out of my newly defined Time class and access the core Time class without renaming my class?

Comment: Just a simple note, parse is a singleton(class) method thus when defining it you should use def self.parase not def parse

Comment: Ended up working when I moved to a class method (also had to change require 'time' to load 'time' in my time_spec for RSpec).  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'time'
class Time
#Opening the singleton class as Time.parse is a singleton method
  class << self
    alias_method :orig_parse, :parse
    def parse(str)
      @time = orig_parse str
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can still reference the old parse method using `Time.orig_parse`

Comment: Hmm yeah that's essentially what I have, but RSpec is complaining that 'parse' is an undefined method for 'Time' when I try to run my spec.

Comment: Ignore my last, just refreshed, will try that.

Comment: That's because you need to require 'time'